# Is it possible to set up OpenMP 4.0 in VisualStudio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, openmp

Is it possible to set up OpenMP newer than the version 2.0 in VisualStudio environment?

Maybe it's possible to set another compiler to run the code (like Intel C++ Compiler) or something?

Comment: Not with Microsoft's compiler but it is possible with Intel's compiler integrated into Visual Studio.

Comment: What feature in OpenMP 4.0 do you want that's not in OpenMP 2.0?

Comment: Clang offers a driver called [clang-cl](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#clang-cl) which integrates quite nicely with Visual Studio. An installer package can be found [here](http://llvm.org/builds/). Since Clang [supoprts](http://blog.llvm.org/2015/05/openmp-support_22.html) OpenMP, you should be able to use a newer version than 2.0. But be aware that there might be compatibility issues regarding the Microsoft STL implementation.

Comment: @Zboson Tasks, atomics, SIMD, offload,...

Comment: @smkanadl Clang OpenMP is not at 4.0 standard yet. Not sure about ETA.

Comment: You could use mingw-w64 and use Visual Studio as an editor/debugger or use use [VS code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) or use Qt Creator or just use emacs on Windows. What do you really want Visual Studio for?

Comment: @Zboson well, I'm just used to developing in there